# convert `com.ning.http.client.ListenableFuture[Any]` into `scala.concurrent.Future[Any]`

Tags: scala, future, asynchttpclient

Is there any way I can convert a variable of type `com.ning.http.client.ListenableFuture[A]` into a type `scala.concurrent.Future[A]`

in other words what would be the content of the function

```
def toFuture[A](a: com.ning.http.client.ListenableFuture[A]):scala.concurrent.Future[A] = ???
```

I am specifically in the case where `A = com.ning.http.client.Response`

Note that `com.ning.http.client.ListenableFuture[A]` is not the same as `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` (and hence [this proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026601) does not solve the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the same as with guava's `ListenableFuture`, although a little more constrained due to more constrained signature.

First, you need to get a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to add a callback. Since your Scala code interacts with a Java library, I'd suggest to define your pool of `scala.concurrent.ExecutorService`s based on Java Executors - that way you can retain both the instance of an Executor and an ExecutorService, something like the following:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) // use it for Java futures
implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(executor) // use it for Scala futures
```

The above steps are not needed if you want to process everything in different pools. In case you want to use an existing `ExecutionContext`, here's a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/5245161) I googled.

Then, to convert the `ListenableFuture` into a `Future`, I'd do something like this (considering some exception semantics of `java.util.concurrent.Future`):

```
def toFuture[A](a: ListenableFuture[A]): Future[A] = {
  val promise = Promise[A]()
  a.addListener(new Runnable {
    def run() = {
      try {
        promise.success(a.get)
      } catch {
        case ex: ExecutionException => promise.failure(ex.getCause)
        case ex => promise.failure(ex)
      }
    }
  }, executor)
  promise.future
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I get `object creation impossible, since method run in trait Runnable of type ()Unit is not defined` any idea?